# How does this lua function convert bits to 32 bit

Tags: math, lua, bit

I found this function and I'm trying to figure out how it converts each character which is 8 bits into 32 bits. The code for the function is below.

```
local function getBits32(streamString)
  local W, X, Y, Z  = string.byte(streamString, streamPosition, streamPositon + 3);
  
  streamPosition = streamPosition + 4;
  
  return (Z * 16777216) + (Y * 65536) + (X * 256) + W;
end;
```

Comment: It reads little-endian 32-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: yah but where does the 16777216 value come from i don't understand where it comes from and why its used

Comment: it equals to 2^24

Comment: hmm how does this all add up to 32 bits

Comment: that could also be written like (Z * 2^24) + (Y * 2^16) + (X * 2^8) + (W * 2^0)

Comment: You should add example input to your function

Comment: well yeah but why do we do it like that shouldnt it be 2 ^ 32 and if not why

Comment: It actually is a set of 4 digits in radix 256.

Comment: @reet15 you can't fit `2^32` in a 32 bit number only `(2^32)-1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's reading WWXXYYZZ
A byte, holds values from 0-255 *( 0x00 to 0xFF )* so `W` holds those.

To count any higher that, you need to multiply by 256.
`(X * 256)`

any higher that, you need to multiply *again* by 256.
`(Y * 256 *256)` is the same as `(Y * 65536)`

And finally, multiply **again** by 256.
`(Z * 256 *256 *256)` is the same as `(Z * 16777216)`

Add them all together, and none of those values overlap.
Multiplying is just a programming trick to keep the values from collididing with one-another, so they can be streamed into the register in one sequential chunk.

---

If you took a values of `3, 4, 5, 6` and you just added them, without premultiplying, you'd get 18.  That's no good because the computer has no idea where to put each byte.  Let's say it's RGBA.  ok, now you have a dim red pixel, but where's your green, blue and alpha channels?

That's why they are multiplied, so that the entire construct can be serialized.
`3 + (4 *256) + (5 *256 *256) + (6 *256 *256 *256)` = ...
I'm not gonna math it, you get the idea.